# Error: RuntimeError: Object's name 'Done' is not unique. in Maya python

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I am creating a Ui using maya python cmd.

My code is given below..

**code**

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

window = cmds.window( title="Render",widthHeight=(300,200),minimizeButton=True,maximizeButton=True )       

inner_child_5 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2)

for val in range(0,2):     
    cmds.checkBox(label="layer")
    cmds.text("Done",width=150, height=10,align='left')
cmds.showWindow( window )
```

I have stuck on an error please help me to solve this error

**Error:**

> Error: RuntimeError: file  line 6: Object's name 'Done' is not unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a silly mistake. i forget to put label on line 6....

```
cmds.text(label = "Done",width=150, height=10,align='left')
```

Answer (score 2):

You try to create the text UI element in a loop. The first time everything works fine, but the second time the UI element already exists. Try to create it with a unique name like this:

```
cmds.text("Done" + str(val), .....)
```

Or simply ignore it and use the label argument

```
cmds.text(label="Done", .....)
```

Comment: what is the difference with label and without label ?

Comment: not using the label, cmds.text assumes that you want the same text as the name of the ui element. But you could do cmds.text("Done", label="I write here smth else", .....)